# Create JSON in javascript and create a file on webserver via ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I've searched and read all I can find on the subject but can't get it to work at all.

I'm creating an array in javascript and then trying to use ajax to send to a php so it creates a json file on the webserver. Sorry if the lingo is off but this is my first attemp at working with ajax and php.

The array looks something like this but with more elements, i think the [] might cause a problem but I have no idea how to get rid of them....

```
[{"elementId":"ID","elementValue":"VALUE","elementType":"text","legendActive":"false"}]
```

Here's the code i have, I'm not sure the path is correct but I tried many different variations with no success...

Javascript and ajax...

```
function saveUserInputs(){
    var userSettings=[];
    inputs=$('form').find(':input:not(:submit), fieldset');
    inputs.each(function(){
        if (this.id.length>0){
            var elementId=$(this).prop('id');
            var elementValue=$(this).val();
            var elementType=$(this).prop('type');
            var elementChecked=$(this).prop('checked');
            var legendActive=$(this).hasClass('disabled-legend-element');
            userSettings.push({elementId: elementId, elementValue: elementValue, elementType: elementType, elementChecked: elementChecked, legendActive: legendActive});
        };
    });

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url: "http://www.lacomptabilite.ca/public_html/test.php",
        dataType : "json",
        data : { "json" : JSON.stringify(userSettings)}, 
        success: function (data) {alert(data); },
        error: function() {alert("Error!");}
    });         
};
```

PHP, which is located in the public_html folder on the server...

```
<?php
   $json = $_POST['json'];

   if (json_decode($json) != null) { /* sanity check */
     $file = fopen('new_map_data.json','w');
     fwrite($file, $json);
     fclose($file);
   } else {
     // handle error 
     echo 'empty';
   }
?>
```

I can't even get the success or failure functions to work. Any one have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Moved all my files over to the web server as suggested but still getting a 403 forbidden error. When I check the port for the php file it's 80 and when I check it from JS it's blank, could that be the problem?

EDIT #2: Turns out it had nothing to do with a communication or permissions problem. Problem what one of the string elements I was sending over was `{"id":"panelProfile","value":null,"type":"select-one"}` and for some reason ajax or php don't like having the word "select" in the json file. Changed it to "combobox" and everything works fine.

Comment: `failure` of course isn't an option for $.ajax, what you're looking for is `error`. I would expect the `error` to always occur since neither `'empty'`, nor `no content` are valid json json strings to match your `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Is your code running on `http://www.lacomptabilite.ca`? If not, then you will likely get CORS issues...

Comment: Check out this function in jQuery - will save you a ton of headache: [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).  In your case, as simple as: `var userSettings = $('form').serialize();`

Comment: @Kevin B thanks, I copied and pasted that code from an answer that was on SO. I'll make the change.

Comment: Realize that the dataType given in your ajax call is about the returned value, not about the sent value.

Comment: @KevinB - good point.  Was thinking of saving coding effort on the javascript side, but it just transfers it to the PHP side....

Comment: @Lee Taylor no the code is running locally, other then the php file which is on the server. I can run the php locally if that makes my life easier ;)

Comment: @JoMojo all depends on what the error is. Press F12 and look for one.

Comment: @Kevin B well the eror msg is now working, thanks. I can't use F12 which makes it that much harder to figure out the problem. I'm writting a SketchUp plugin which doesn't allow F12 in the webdialogs.

Comment: @cale_b thanks I'll look into that and see if it helps me out.

Comment: What do the 2nd and 3rd arguments of the error callback contain?

Comment: @KevinB This is what I get from the error {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"No Transport"}

Comment: Looks like a possible CORS error to me, which means either implement CORS in php, or move the code to the same domain as the php.

Comment: I'll check out CORS, never heard of it before. When you say move the code you mean the JS code correct?

Comment: i mean, whatever is sending the ajax request, needs to be served by the same origin that the php is being served from, otherwise you have to follow CORS standards.

Comment: and by origin, i mean same protocol, domain, and port. so, `http://www.lacomptabilite.ca`

Comment: @Kevin B ok copied the files over to the server but keep getting 0  error, can't find file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### FU ERROR 403!

As per my edit here's what I found with updated working code. Error 403 can be caused by a number of things which are not obvious, one seems to be file size and another which was my problem was using the word 'select' within my json file. I think this might have to do with the fact it's a reserved word related to SQL but I'm not 100% sure all I know is it didn't work!

If you're sending files cross domain you need to add this to javascript...

```
 $.support.cors=true;
```

...and this to $.ajax...

```
crossDomain: true,
```

Here's the complete code that worked for me... I added 2 different urls for information purposes only, one is for cross domain path and the commented out one is if all your files are on the same domain, port and protocol. If that's the case you don't need  `$.support.cors=true;` and `crossDomain: true,`

AJAX:

```
$.support.cors=true;   
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    method: "post",
    //url: "/php/userJson.php",
    url: "http://www.yourDomain.com/php/userJson.php",
    dataType: "json",

    data: {"json" : userSettings},
    success: function (suc) {alert (JSON.stringify(suc))},
    error: function(error) {alert (JSON.stringify(error))}
});
```

Here's the php code, I left some commented out lines that I found useful for trouble shooting purposes.

PHP:

```
<?php
    //echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
    //echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
    //echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]; 
    //echo $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]; 
    //echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]; 
    //echo $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]; 
    //echo $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; 

    $json=$_POST['json'];

    if (json_decode($json) != null){ 
        $file=fopen('user_data.json','w+');
        fwrite($file, $json);
        fclose($file);
    }else{
        echo "empty";
    }
?>
```

EDIT: ADDED CODE TO RETRIEVE FILE FROM SERVER...

```
$.ajax({
  crossDomain: true,
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://www.yourDomain.com/php/user_data.json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (success) {alert (JSON.stringify(success))},
  error: function(error) {alert (JSON.stringify(error))}
});
```

Comment: yes, the issue with `select` is likely either due to an over-protective firewall or something in php that is filtering responses, both as preventative measures against sql injection. (but it's a bit weird to be filtering the response.... usually only the request is filtered)

Comment: @Kevin B thanks for the confirmation... though I don't think I'm doing any of that but maybe my ISP is for some reason.

Comment: One other thing that maybe you can clairify for me, I can retrieve a file no problem as along as I send it first, even if it already exists on the server I can't retrieve it without first sending it. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: well, if  you don't send a file, there wouldn't be one to read, right?

Comment: Ha yes correct, but if I sent it previously in another session and I go back to 'get' it I get an error 'No Transport'. I thought it was because I didn't add crossDomain: true, but I added it and still the samething.

Comment: What does your get route look like in php? or is it accessing it directly

Comment: I don't have anything in php in regards to get the file, all I have is the ajax code I posted in my answer.

Comment: but, it works if you first post it, and then get it. that's strange.

Comment: Yeah even for a total newb like me it makes no sense why that doesn't work.

Comment: @Kevin B Found the problem was missing $.support.cors=true;  in my new function to test 'get' :/. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmm... that shouldn't have any effect, $.support.cors is a flag that jQuery sets that specifies whether or not the browser supports cors. Setting it to true shouldn't magically make the browser support cors. What browser? crossdomain: true is also almost never needed, it is only needed if you want to send a request to the same origin as if it were a cross-origin request.

Comment: Well it's a watered down version of IE9 that Sketchup API uses to create plugins, also the html file is local to my machine so maybe that's why I need those?

Comment: very possible. jQuery is likely mis-identifying the cors support due to that.

Comment: A little off topic but, I can get the json file and converting it to an array like this...success: function(success) {var userData=JSON.stringify(success);  userData=$.parseJSON(userData); },. Now how can use the array in another function or even within the same function? I need to iterate the array.

Comment: Found the answer to iterating the json file here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990097/iterating-through-json-within-a-ajax-success

Answer (score 0):

Properly you should use jQuery functions serialize, fix the userSettings  and replace with this code

```
var userSettings = $('form').serialize();
```

Comment: and... how would the OP have to change the php to have it accept the data in this format and save it as json in a .json file?

Comment: You will receive the post as json $_POST['json'] and then save it to file  $file = fopen('test.json','w'); fwrite($file, $_POST['json']); fclose($file);

Comment: no... the way you set it up he would receive $_POST['inputname'] with the input's value, not a json post var. $('form').serialize() creates a param string.