# JSON Parse failed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am having JSON as

```
{
   "js":[
      [
         "556",
         "Name the Bengali film television and stage actor who passed away recently?",
         "Gaynar Baksha",
         "Byomkesh Bakshi",
         "Pijush Ganguly",
         "Kaushik Ganguly",
         "Pijush Ganguly",
         "Beginner",
         "Android",
         "First Mobile OS by google"
      ],
      [
         "557",
         "Venkateswara Rao passed away recently. He was a",
         "Telugu poet",
         "Telugu director",
         "Telugu actor",
         "Telugu lyricist",
         "Telugu actor",
         "Beginner",
         "Android",
         "First Mobile OS by google"
      ],
      [
         "559",
         "Which Indian cricketer who became the fourth player to register hundred in ODIs? ",
         "Ishant Sharma",
         "Virendra Sehwag",
         "MS Dhoni",
         "Virat Kohli",
         "Virat Kohli",
         "Beginner",
         "Android",
         "First Mobile OS by google"
      ],
      [
         "568",
         "First Android Mobile ?",
         "Motorola",
         "Nokia",
         "Lenevo",
         "HTC",
         "Motorola",
         "Moderate",
         "Android",
         "Moto is the first company"
      ],
      [
         "569",
         "col1",
         "col2",
         "col3",
         "col4",
         "",
         "",
         "",
         "",
         ""
      ],
      [
         "570",
         "\u092d\u093e\u0930\u0924 \u0915\u0947 \u092a\u093e\u0938 125 \u092a\u0930\u092e\u093e\u0923\u0941 \u0939\u0925\u093f\u092f\u093e\u0930, \u091c\u093e\u0928\u093f\u090f; \u0915\u093f\u0938\u0915\u0940 \u0915\u093f\u0924\u0928\u0940 \u0924\u093e\u0915\u0924",
         "\u092a\u093e\u0938 125 \u092a\u0930\u092e\u093e\u0923\u0941",
         "data",
         "Php",
         "",
         "",
         "",
         "",
         ""
      ],
      [
         "571",
         "\u092a\u093e\u0938 125 \u092a\u0930\u092e\u093e\u0923\u0941",
         "\u0915\u093f\u0938\u0915\u0940 \u0915\u093f\u0924\u0928\u0940 \u0924\u093e\u0915\u0924",
         "video",
         "excel with php",
         "",
         "",
         "",
         "",
         ""
      ]
   ]
}
```

When I am checking it on http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ it is showing correctly i.e. validated, but when I am appending it in table in HTML using AJAX and Jquery it is failed to append.

My code to append it is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "searchall.php",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        var response = $.parseJSON(data);

        for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            $('.dataTableReport').append('<tr style="text-align:center;"><td style="width:6.8%"><span><input name="qid" type="checkbox" value="' + response[i].Question_id + '" style="margin-left: 5%;"/>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<label for="qid">' + response[i].Question_id + '</label></span></td><td style="width:20.77%">' + response[i].Question + '</td><td style="width:9.3%">' + response[i].opt1 + '</td><td style="width:9%">' + response[i].opt2 + '</td><td style="width:9%">' + response[i].opt3 + '</td><td style="width:9.8%">' + response[i].opt4 + '</td><td style="width:9.1%">' + response[i].correct + '</td><td style="width:17.3%">' + response[i].explain + '</td><td style="width:5%" onclick="edit(' + response[i].Question_id + ')"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></td><td style="width:5%" onclick="deletee(' + response[i].Question_id + ')"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></td></tr>');
        }
    }
});
```

All the fields in table are filled with "undefined"

How to parse JSON, and how do I append?

I have modified my JSON as

`[
   {
      "Question_id":"556",
      "Question":"Name the Bengali film television and stage actor who passed away recently?",
      "opt1":"Gaynar Baksha",
      "opt2":"Byomkesh Bakshi",
      "opt3":"Pijush Ganguly",
      "opt4":"Kaushik Ganguly",
      "correct":"Pijush Ganguly",
      "Level":"Beginner",
      "Category":"Android",
      "explain":"First Mobile OS by google"
   },
   {
      "Question_id":"557",
      "Question":"Venkateswara Rao passed away recently. He was a",
      "opt1":"Telugu poet",
      "opt2":"Telugu director",
      "opt3":"Telugu actor",
      "opt4":"Telugu lyricist",
      "correct":"Telugu actor",
      "Level":"Beginner",
      "Category":"Android",
      "explain":"First Mobile OS by google"
   },
   {
      "Question_id":"559",
      "Question":"Which Indian cricketer who became the fourth player to register hundred in ODIs? ",
      "opt1":"Ishant Sharma",
      "opt2":"Virendra Sehwag",
      "opt3":"MS Dhoni",
      "opt4":"Virat Kohli",
      "correct":"Virat Kohli",
      "Level":"Beginner",
      "Category":"Android",
      "explain":"First Mobile OS by google"
   },
   {
      "Question_id":"568",
      "Question":"First Android Mobile ?",
      "opt1":"Motorola",
      "opt2":"Nokia",
      "opt3":"Lenevo",
      "opt4":"HTC",
      "correct":"Motorola",
      "Level":"Moderate",
      "Category":"Android",
      "explain":"Moto is the first company"
   },
   {
      "Question_id":"569",
      "Question":"col1",
      "opt1":"col2",
      "opt2":"col3",
      "opt3":"col4",
      "opt4":"",
      "correct":"",
      "Level":"",
      "Category":"",
      "explain":""
   },
   {
      "Question_id":"570",
      "Question":"\u092d\u093e\u0930\u0924 \u0915\u0947 \u092a\u093e\u0938 125 \u092a\u0930\u092e\u093e\u0923\u0941 \u0939\u0925\u093f\u092f\u093e\u0930, \u091c\u093e\u0928\u093f\u090f; \u0915\u093f\u0938\u0915\u0940 \u0915\u093f\u0924\u0928\u0940 \u0924\u093e\u0915\u0924",
      "opt1":"\u092a\u093e\u0938 125 \u092a\u0930\u092e\u093e\u0923\u0941",
      "opt2":"data",
      "opt3":"Php",
      "opt4":"",
      "correct":"",
      "Level":"",
      "Category":"",
      "explain":""
   },
   {
      "Question_id":"571",
      "Question":"\u092a\u093e\u0938 125 \u092a\u0930\u092e\u093e\u0923\u0941",
      "opt1":"\u0915\u093f\u0938\u0915\u0940 \u0915\u093f\u0924\u0928\u0940 \u0924\u093e\u0915\u0924",
      "opt2":"video",
      "opt3":"excel with php",
      "opt4":"",
      "correct":"",
      "Level":"",
      "Category":"",
      "explain":""
   }
]`

and still the following code is not working

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "sall.php" ,
                dataType: "text",
                success : function(data) 
                {
                var response = $.parseJSON(data);       
for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) 
                {
$('.dataTableReport').append('<tr style="text-align:center;"><td style="width:6.8%"><span><input name="qid" type="checkbox" value="' + response[i].Question_id + '" style="margin-left: 5%;"/>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<label for="qid">' + response[i].Question_id + '</label></span></td><td style="width:20.77%">' + response[i].Question + '</td><td style="width:9.3%">' + response[i].opt1 + '</td><td style="width:9%">' + response[i].opt2 + '</td><td style="width:9%">' + response[i].opt3 + '</td><td style="width:9.8%">' + response[i].opt4 + '</td><td style="width:9.1%">' + response[i].correct + '</td><td style="width:17.3%">' + response[i].explain + '</td><td style="width:5%" onclick="edit('+response[i].Question_id+')"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></td><td style="width:5%" onclick="deletee('+response[i].Question_id+')"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></td></tr>');
                }         
         }
         });
```

I am getting the response from server but at line `var response = $.parseJSON(data);` the execution gets terminate. I am confused why parseJSON(data); is not working?

Comment: Are you sure that your server is sending a response? Can you check the response you get from your server with a browser's developer console?

Comment: Values you have in "js" property are just lists of values, you won't be able to access them by using keys like "Question_id", only by integer indexes

Comment: Yes I am getting the response

Comment: There is no need to set `contentType` if you are not sending any data to the server.

Comment: on ajax success callback do console.log(data) and check if you are receiving data in correct format or not.

Comment: I am getting this  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"> along with response

Comment: thnks...removing <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"> worked for me..

Answer (score 2):

if you change your php code, so that it returns **json** instead of **text**, then you  don't need to parse the returned data (`var response = $.parseJSON(data);`  ). Then the code below will probably work in this case:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "sall.php" ,
       dataType: "json",
       success : function(data) {
            // this works with the original js data
             $.each(data.js, function(index, item) {
                // the two lines below are for testing, you can replace 
                // those with your $('.dataTableReport').append code
                console.debug(item[0])
                console.debug(item[1])
             });         
        }
  });
```

In the above code the `dataType` was changed to `json`, and jQuery's [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method was used. I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/nLg8dqhk/) that shows how `$.each` loops through your json items. Here is a link for similar type of Stackoverflow question: [Iterating through JSON within a $.ajax success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990097/iterating-through-json-within-a-ajax-success):

Answer (score 0):

Update line

```
for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < response['js'].length; i++)
```

And replace

```
response[i] -> response['js'][i]
```

within html appending flow.

Other option is to replace line:

```
response = $.parseJSON(data);
```

to

```
response = $.parseJSON(data)['js'];
```

Comment: probably it's not working because you are trying to access  properties of items which doesn't exist, so you need to modify string which you are appending to use existing properties name.